# Issue running chrome and chrome driver in docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, installation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new with docker and i'm trying to extract some text data using selenium and tried to install chrome browser and drivers in my docker container. The image build is getting completed and upon launching the container and the script to scrape data using the driver i'm getting the following error.
[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiI3i.png)
[Getting this error>>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh0HK.png)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Define the base URL
base_url = "https://example.com/search"

# Define the search term
search_term = "time series analysis"

# Set up Selenium
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location="/usr/bin/chrome-linux64/chrome"
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run headless browser
service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver")  # Path to chromedriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Construct the URL with the search term as a parameter
url = f"https://journals.plos.org/plosone/search?filterJournals=PLoSONE&q={search_term}"

# Open the URL in the headless browser
driver.get(url)

# Wait for a few seconds to ensure the page is fully loaded
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust this wait time as needed

# Get the page source after JavaScript execution
page_source = driver.page_source

# Close the headless browser
driver.quit()

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find the article element with class "searchResults" and id "search-results"
article = soup.find('article', class_='searchResults', id='search-results')
links=temp.find_all('a')
hrefs = [tag.a['href'] for tag in links]
```

[Ignore rest of the code as the focus is only on connection and testing that]
Error:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chrome-linux64/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:

1. Tried adding [options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")] but was of no use.
2. I checked the permissions of the chrome and the driver. It's set to executable.
3. I mentioned the paths to both the chrome and chrome driver in my code.
4. I tried to run chrome --version and chromedriver --version in my container and getting cannot recognize chrome as output.

can you please suggest me what's wrong with my code. I'll add the docker file and requirements.txt also below.
[you can see the list of files in both the directories chrome and chrome driver here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68PRU.png)

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qQj0.png)

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2whA.png)

[Please ignore the formatting of the question as this is my first time posting on stack overflow]

Comment: `docker run -d -p 5555:5555 selenium/standalone-chrome` in code `webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:5555")`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the Dockerfile, error message, _etc._ in plain text?